# Creating a d.ts file for existing module

Tags: module, typescript

I'm trying to create a `d.ts` file for the [React StaticContainer](https://github.com/reactjs/react-static-container) library.

The installed lib in NPM looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');

var StaticContainer = (function (_React$Component) {

  function StaticContainer() {
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  return StaticContainer;
})(React.Component);

module.exports = StaticContainer;
```

An example usage is like this:

```
var StaticContainer = require('react-static-container');
```

And I'm not sure how to create a declaration for this and use it in TypeScript. So far from my research I've come up with this:

```
import * as StaticContainer from 'react-static-container'
```

And this `d.ts` file:

```
interface StaticContainer extends React.Component<any, any> {
  shouldUpdate?:boolean;
}

declare module "react-static-container" {
  export = StaticContainer;
}
```

However TSC gives me this error:

> Error:(3, 34) TS2497: Module '"react-static-container"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

I'm rather confused how the `module.exports = StaticContainer` should translate to a `d.ts` file. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

> Module '"react-static-container"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

Exactly what the error says. You need to import `export =` style libraries with `import require`. This is because of the ES6 spec.

```
import StaticContainer =  require('react-state-container');
```

Comment: I'm sure it means what is says, most error messages do ;) but I don't have the context to understand it... "this is because of the ES6 spec" unfortunately doesn't further my understanding. Can you elaborate? The code you posted doesn't work, now I get `TS2304: Cannot find name 'StaticContainer'.` I'm guessing my `d.ts` does not correctly reflect the way the original library is exported.

Comment: @Aaron got exactly same issue. had to define the same name before as var. Eg, `let StaticContainer : any` in this case. Don't sure why it happens.

Comment: ES6 spec allows you to export individual items. Exporting an *object* is not statically analyzable and not supported.