# what is the correct way to add type definition for this module

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I have a module, without any typescript definition, that I use in my code like this:

```
import * as Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';


render () {
 return <Switch/>
}
```

Since `react-bootstrap-switch` doesnt have a type definition, I am trying to create one for it.

I have tried:

```
declare module 'react-bootstrap-switch'
{
    import React = require("react");
    class Switch extends React.Component<{onColor?:string},{} >
    {}

    export  = Switch;
}
```

However this results in the import statement in the original code throwing this error:

```
error TS2497: Module ''react-bootstrap-switch'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

What is the correct way to write the module definition that satisfies the code on top?

Comment: Try updating `class Switch` to `interface Switch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements are used for `.ts` files not for `.d.ts` files. For those you need to use the `///<reference .../>` tags or simple `import React = __React;` type imports.

Here is what I could come up with using the [react.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/36c6ce86fb64bafb28ec95dc78c6b98228b45c8d/react/react.d.ts) file and the [React Switch](https://github.com/Julusian/react-bootstrap-switch/blob/master/src/coffee/react-bootstrap-switch.coffee) source code.

```
///<reference path="../react/react.d.ts"/>
declare module 'react-bootstrap-switch'
{
    function Switch(): __React.ClassicComponentClass;

    export  = Switch;
}
```

How you use typescript, and how you write definition files for JS libraries are two completely different things. If this does not work for you then I suppose I could pull down the repos and get it building.

**Update**

Ok I have a working version

```
declare module 'react-bootstrap-switch'{
    interface SwitchProps{
        onColor?: string
    }

    class Switch extends __React.Component<SwitchProps, {}>{}

    export = Switch;
}
```

Usage `import Switch = require('react-bootstrap-switch');`

And before you comment saying that you can't switch the import...

Please read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818337/creating-a-d-ts-file-for-existing-module#answer-33818423) explaining why. And please run the code. You will see that the JS version of the library still loads as expected and still runs.

I need to credit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818337/creating-a-d-ts-file-for-existing-module) and [this definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ffceea9dd124d277c4597c7bd12930666ec074c5/react-spinkit/react-spinkit.d.ts) for their help in this.

My test file for compiling:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Switch = require('react-bootstrap-switch');

var b = <div></div>;
var a = <Switch/>;
```

The resulting output:

```
var React = require('react');
var Switch = require('react-bootstrap-switch');
var b = React.createElement("div", null);
var a = React.createElement(Switch, null);
```

As you can see the output is identical for either import and the build is error free.

And tsconfig.js:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es3",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "built",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: this results in the same error as i mentioned. Also imports are indeed allowed and used inside .d.ts file. Example here: https://github.com/rcchen/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d9978a3c3c91377b94c59a06d82eee292902b123/react-router/react-router.d.ts

Comment: @pdeva updated answer. I now receive no build errors and have clean js output.

Answer (score 1):

Try some variation of the following 3 lines added to your original definition:

```
declare module 'react-bootstrap-switch'
{
    import React = require("react");
    class Switch extends React.Component<{onColor?:string},{}>
    {}

    namespace Switch {}
    var s: Switch;
    export = Switch;
}
```

Your `import * as Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';` should not need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**main.tsx**

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./switch.d.ts" />
import React = __React;
import * as Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';


var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Switch.Component name="test" />
    }
});
```

**switch.d.ts**

```
///<reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts"/>
declare module 'react-bootstrap-switch'
{
    import React = require("react");

    export class Component extends React.Component<any, any> {}
}
```

Comment: the `import * as Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';` cannot be changed. This is how the library works. What is needed is a module definition that satisfies the `import * as Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';` part. your answer has the import modified

Comment: did you try running your code? `Switch` is `null` unless you do `import * as Switch`

Comment: I'm not on my primary computer, so no, I didn't try it. I tried to update it to use the import you want. I'm not sure it works but syntactically it is ok. If it does not work for you, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as a bug in TypeScript:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6656

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove declare module part and have your Switch class declaration like this:

```
import React = require("react");
export default class Switch extends React.Component<{onColor?:string},{} >
{}
```

then import it like this:

```
import Switch from 'react-bootstrap-switch';
```

or if you prefer:

```
import React = require("react");
export class Switch extends React.Component<{onColor?:string},{} >
{}
```

and

```
import {Switch} from 'react-bootstrap-switch';
```

EDIT

If you are creating definition only then to fix your error you should import your definition using the syntax like this:

```
import Switch = require('react-bootstrap-switch');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: we are creating a 'definition' file for an existing javascript module. we are not writing the module from scratch in typescript.

Comment: i am not asking for a modified import statement. the import is how it is and it works. I am asking for a module definition that would be valid for the import.